# What does "logical basis" mean?

Tags: soft-question, foundations

I am reading the book by Morris Kline "Mathematics, the Loss of Certainty". It mentioned that irrational numbers, negative numbers and complex numbers lack logical basis. So, how to *define* logical basis? And how can we say a logical basis is sound?

### ADD 1

I have a feeling that the logical basis cannot be defined. Because we need *logic* to define something. And in this scenario, it is kind of like *a vicious circle*.

### ADD 2

Add some context from the [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=RNwnUL33epsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

Comment: Honestly, lacking the context provided by an excerpt from the text (as well as the discussion leading up to such a statement), I'm not sure that a reasonable answer is possible.  At a guess, the phrase is being used in a vernacular, rather than technical, manner.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for your reply. I added some context.

Comment: I think "logical basis" is meant as an ordinary English phrase, rather than a technical mathematical term.

Comment: Based on the excerpt you have posted, I am going to reafirm my previous statement:  the phrase here is being used in a vernacular sense.  This is a history of mathematics.  In the 19th century (and prior) there were concerns that much of mathematics was not on a firm logical foundation; things like the negative and complex numbers were poorly understood and poorly justified.  Most of those concerns were dealt with in the early 20th century (modulo a Gödel or two).

Comment: "logical basis" must be understood in a loosely way. It means: a well-defined set of basic principles and rules that are non contradictory or (at least) devoided of known paradoxes.

Comment: The issue of "circularity" is useless: obviously we need *logic* to "reason about" something, mathematics included. But we use logic also to "reason about" logic itself; see formal logic and mathematica logic. But in turn mathematical logic is a mathematical discipline.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. Your reply is very helpful to me. And I will check the relation/difference between *formal logic* and *mathematical logic*.